# Print status update without loop iteration (python)

Tags: python, progress, status

I have a very simple function that is just a list of data writes, but each write takes 5-10s, so the function takes about an hour to run.  Since there is no loop, there is no iteration variable.  What is the best way to update progress to the user?

Comment: Update the progress between the write instructions?

Comment: where is the data coming from, and what type of container the data is in?! How do you write it without iterating on the items (for which, the write takes 5-10s)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the `logging` module? You can create different kinds of handlers to, well, handle log messages. Here's a simple example, but the general idea is you can just put logging messages in your script that write to a file, a stream that prints to the console, or something else.

```
import datetime
import logging
import time

logger = logging.getLogger('a_name')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
sh = logging.StreamHandler()  # prints to console
logger.addHandler(sh)

 with open('/tmp/test_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    logger.info('beginning writing file at ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    time.sleep(30)  # this is a proxy for doing some file writing
    logger.info('the time now is' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    ...
    loggering.info('file done being written')
```

You might want to look info formatting the log messages so you don't have to include the datetime str in an in-elegant way like I did.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This would require inserting logger calls throughout the function, correct?

Comment: @m100psi yep. You can do some relatively fancy stuff with logging (my answer is not an example) though I echo the concerns of the comments on the OP about iteration, data source, etc.